# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service {....} can't instantiate class; no empty constructor

Tags: android

I am having an error when trying to start a Service in my Android APP
I start the service rigth before pausing the Activity, so I can upload some info to the server.

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service  can't instantiate class ; no empty constructor
```

The problem comes when I start the service:

```
 protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    EditText nicknameText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_Nickname);
    EditText emailText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_Email);

    String strNickname = nicknameText.getText().toString();
    String strEmail = emailText.getText().toString();

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mGameSettings.edit();
    editor.putString(GAME_PREFERENCES_NICKNAME, strNickname);
    editor.putString(GAME_PREFERENCES_EMAIL, strEmail);

    editor.commit();

    //Antes de salir lanzamos una actividad nueva para hacer el upload de la info

    Intent uploadService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),UploaderService.class);
    startService(uploadService);


}
```

The Service will then start an AsyncTask

```
public  class UploaderService extends Service{

    public UploaderService(){
        super();
    }

    private UpLoadUserData upLoadUserData;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        upLoadUserData = new UpLoadUserData();
        upLoadUserData.execute();
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Settings and image upload requested");
        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // no binding
        return null;
    }
}
```

The manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.androidbook.btdt.hour6"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0"
    android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10"></uses-sdk>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:debuggable="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".QuizSplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="QuizHelpActivity"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name="QuizMenuActivity"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name="QuizScoresActivity"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name="QuizSettingsActivity"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name="QuizGameActivity"></activity>
        <service android:name="QuizSettingsActivity$UploaderService"></service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: **TL:DR**.  You need to simply this a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you cannot have a `Service` that is an ordinary nested class. It would have to be a `static` nested class.

Second, having a `Service` that is a `static` nested class of an `Activity` is very strange.

Third, having a `Service` spawning an `AsyncTask`, rather than just using `IntentService`, is very strange.

Fourth, replace `getApplicationContext()` with `this`. Only use `getApplicationContext()` when you know why you are using `getApplicationContext()`, and you do not need it here.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot!

I could successefully satart the Service by extending it from IntentService insetead of Service

```
  public static  class UploaderService extends IntentService{

    String DEBUG_TAG = UploaderService.class.getSimpleName();

    SharedPreferences mGameSettings;
```

and defining the Intent Service in the Manifest.xml

```
<service android:name=".QuizSettingsActivity$UploaderService"/>
```